# XSD Schema from XML element with attributes and child element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xml file containing some elements:

```
<item name="some_name1" type="text">some_text1</param>
<item name="some_name2" type="text">some_text2</param>
<item name="some_name3" type="text">
    <line>some_line1</line>
    <line>some_line2</line>
    <line>some_line3</line>
</item>
```

Schema for these elements:

```
<xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>                                               
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Unfortunately, this does not support the `line` sub-elements. I tried to add the new elements in different ways, but, unfortunately, still doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true" >
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="line" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

that defines `item` as an element with `line` sub-elements and mixed content - i.e. that can contain also text.